# column names of Cassandra tables using libcql

Tags: c++, cassandra, cql3, libcql

Is there a way to get the column names of a table in Cassandra with libcql (https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver)? I could not find a relevent API calls in the C++ driver.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 2):

cqllib is CQL3 compliant so why not just query the system tables? [The example](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver#minimal-working-example---simple-query-against-systemschema_keyspaces) on the page you linked actually shows how to retrieve information about the keyspaces in the cluster.

As for the columns, the queries you are after:

```
 SELECT * FROM system.schema_columns;
 // or specify a keyspace to make column retrieval more specific 
 SELECT * FROM schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name='ks_name';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The method mentioned by you is definitely doable. However, I was mostly looking for an API on the lines of get_index(...) or column_type() or column_class in cql::cql_result_t Class of libcql. Something like get_column_name(int column_index). This is helpful while iterating over a result set so as to associate the column names to the records. get_index(...) takes the column name to return its index, so what I was looking for is the reverse.